# Introducing functionality stored in a file into another file defining a minor-mode

Tags: files, minor-mode

I am debugging a minor-mode and have split the file into two files.  How would one introduce the functionality in the second file into the minor-mode file?

I have my minor-mode called `rk-bracemarks` and the child file called `rk-counter`.

This is what I have for the minor-mode:

```lisp
    ;;;###autoload
    (define-minor-mode rk-minor-mode
      "Emphasise brace marks." 
      :lighter " rk"  ; indicator in mode-line
      
      (font-lock-remove-keywords nil rk-font-lock)
    
      (require 'rk-counter)
      
      (when rk-minor-mode  ; evaluates true when mode enabled
        (rk-autobracketing)
        (rk-bracemk-companion "expression")
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil rk-font-lock 'append)
        (set (make-local-variable 'jit-lock-contextually) t))
      
      (when font-lock-mode
        (if (fboundp 'font-lock-flush)
            (font-lock-flush)
          (with-no-warnings (font-lock-fontify-buffer)) )) )
```

Comment: The file size indicates that you should actually split the functionality into multiple libraries. Then you can write appropriate `autoload` statements such that the child library is loaded on demand or you can `require` the child library in the parent library. If that is not appropriate for any reason you can still use `load-file`.

Comment: I do not have experience using child libraries, as up till now I have used a number of relatively short minor-modes.  But as more work is done, I would like to have a parent minor-mode that calls several child libraries as you mention.  But  am getting dazed on how this can be done.

Comment: What is usually better, calling  `(load "path-to-file.el")` or `(add-to-list 'load-path path-to-file.el)`.

Comment: I'd suggest then that you start with the simplest method: adding `(load-file "/path/to/child.el")` at the beginning of the parent file will do the trick. That requires no mechanism at all.

Comment: The second of your suggested alternatives does not make sense. Even if you add a directory to `load-path` as you should, that still would not meet your requirements as stated in your question.

Comment: Would I then simply use `(require 'rk-counter)`, because I put `(provide 'rk-counter)` at the end of the child file ?

Comment: That needs additional mechanism: you need to add the *directory* where the `rk-counter.el[c]` file is to your `load-path`.

Comment: I have the file in the same directory as the parent.

Comment: Take a look at questions by others. Do you see a difference? Do you see a long, wandering comment trail in each or your questions and their answers? Please learn from the `help` column here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help. And read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). And [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). Do this and you will **Help yourself** - you'll get more and better answers.